# Need line breaks in database display for jpGraph

Tags: php, mysql, jpgraph

I'm learning how to use jpGraph to display bar graphs. The instructions explain how to create a .txt file with the following data:

```
1700.5   5.0  
1701.5  110.0  
1702.5  16.0  
1703.5  23.0
```

I discovered that it still works if I change the extension to .php. But rather than use a static file, I want to figure out how to display data from a database table. Specifically, I want to display dates and test scores, like this:

```
2015-01-05  10
2015-01-05  50
2015-01-21  80
```

So I replaced the static data with a database query, followed by this code...

```
while ($row = $stm->fetch())
{
 $Test_Score = $row['Test_Score'];
 $Test_Date = $row['Test_Date'];

 $Results[] = ''.$Test_Date.'  '.$Test_Score.'';
}

echo join ($Results, '');
```

The problem is that this displays something like this...

```
2015-01-05  102015-01-05  502015-01-21  80
```

Adding a break doesn't help, apparently because it isn't compatible with jpGraph's code...

```
$Results[] = ''.$Test_Date.'  '.$Test_Score.'<br>';
```

So I'm trying to figure out an alternative way to insert line breaks after each row of code. I'm on a Mac, so I think I'm supposed to use /r/n, but I've also tried /r and /n, enclosed in both double quotes and single quotes.

What's the magic formula?

Comment: line breaks are [`\r\n`](http://fr2.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double) not `/r/n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
$lines = implode(PHP_EOL,$Results); // equal join(PHP_EOL,$Results);
```

Constant `PHP_EOL` automatically set correct line-break of current OS.

Comment: Cool tip, but I'm missing something. I now have this code:
 $Results[] = ''.$Test_Date.'  '.$Test_Score.'';
} ...followed by this line:

$lines = implode(PHP_EOL,$Results); // equal join(PHP_EOL,$Results);
...followed by this code:
echo $lines;
But it displays all the data in a single line, as before.

Comment: @David Blomstrom what you want to do with this `$lines`? How it use? Put  in file?View?

Comment: I'm not sure. I have the same script in two files - the .php file in reference in my post, and another test file where I can actually see the results. So I echo $Results or $lines to see the results. I assume I also have to echo something in the file I'm using with jpGraph in order to create two columns of data.

Comment: @David Blomstrom `file_put_contents('output.txt',$lines);`

Comment: It took me a while to understand what was going on, but I suddenly realized you answered my original question plus another question I was going to ask later. ;)